# Do Videos on the Web on Android Devices play inline or in an video app?

Tags: android, mobile-website, android-video-player

I want to find out wether Videos on Mobile Websites play inline or in a video application. If they play in an video application: are these applications device specific or is it always the same? Does someone have a link to the look of the controls so that I can build a photoshop preview on how my web video will look on Android?

**EDIT**

By inline, I mean that it does not play in an external app like it does on the iphone (opens quicktime player whenever you click a video on m.youtube.com) but that it just plays inside the browser.

Comment: What do you mean by `inline`. Most android browsers are just like any other browser.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 video tag supported on some androids see [HTML5 <video> element on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android)