# Html 5 not working on Android

Tags: android, html, video

Im having trouble getting some html 5 code to work on the android. It works on the ipad no problem:

```
<video id="1" height="270" width="320" poster="http://vls.pete.videolibraryserver.com
/thumbnails/56553550.jpg" src="http://helix.pete.videolibraryserver.com/flash
/56553550_hi.mp4" autostart="false" controls preload="none" />
```

Any ideas why it just comes up with a thumbnail of the video rather than just playing it?

Regards,
Pete

Comment: What version of Android?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

[HTML5 <video> element on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android)