# How to embed a videoview in Webview?

Tags: android, webview, android-videoview

I would like to embed a videoview in a webview. I would like to play an mp4 video on that video view. Please guide me with some pointers so that i can implement this.

---

**Update**
I have only html4 browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was already a question with answer on it.

[HTML5 <video> element on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android)

I think it's what you're looking for...

EDIT:

I dunno why you have only HTML4 but look at this then:

http://www.robinlionheart.com/stds/html4/objvideo

As far as I know you need the quicktime settings for mp4...

Comment: i am having Android 2.1 version.. But HTML5 was not working.. i was able to bring up the page, but the video was not able to be played..

Comment: Hi Beasley.. Thanks for the update.. I tried giving  <object data="file:///<path to my video>" type="video/quicktime" width="320" height="256" standby="Loading&hellip;">
<param name="autoplay" value="false"></object>  But it is not working..

Comment: Hmm... I have to admit I never did it my self. I just read about it.  
I'll let you know if I have something else in my mind