# problem in playing video on android webview using HTML5?

Tags: android

this is my html file...

```
<html>
<head> Demo </head>
<body>
    <h1>HTML 5 - Video Demo</h1>
    <video src="http://www.abc.com/a.m4v" controls="true">
    </video>

    <script>
     document.getElementById('video');
    </script>   
</body>
```

and I'm using this code for java...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.viewr);

    WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    web. getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled (true);
    web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    web. loadUrl ("file:///android_asset/VidDemo.htm");            
    web.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

}

final class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith(".3gp")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(url));
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    }
}
```

but video not appear on screen and also not play. please suggest me what should i do...

Comment: hmm i think this can be useful to you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android

Answer (score 1):

That is because Android's browser does not have any video codecs.

Somehow, you will have to trigger the native video app to open on click. I am looking for a way to do that too.

Comment: To follow up, parse requests made inside your WebView and create an Intent to open the video player with any video url.

Answer (score 0):

It works

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically (false);
            webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled (true);
            webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows (false);
            webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom (false);
            webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled (false);
            webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled (false);
            webView.getSettings().setFixedFontFamily("file:///android_asset/fonts/CamMob.ttf");
            webView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(fontSize + 5);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
            webView.setWebChromeClient(chromeClient);
            webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
}
```

private WebChromeClient chromeClient = new WebChromeClient(){

```
    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        super.onShowCustomView(view, callback); 
        if(view instanceof FrameLayout){
            FrameLayout frame  = (FrameLayout)view;
            if(frame.getFocusedChild()instanceof VideoView){
            VideoView video =  (VideoView)frame.getFocusedChild();
                frame.removeView(video);
                           video.start();

            }
        }
    }

};
```