# how can i make it play video on android/iphone?

Tags: iphone, android, video, mobile

**update 1**

i dont know much about but what i am trying to do is to play the video on both andriod/iphone through html5 as others have stated that i have to use  tag in order to do that...

**end update 1**

**updated:**
here is the code on my html page:

`<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  <source src="movie.mp4"  type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm" />
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>`

**end update:**

here is my code and don't seem its working for android and i am targeting android/iPhone devices. any help?

```
<noscript>
    <object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3423ABDDC63" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
        <param name="src" value="http://hostname/images/Large.jpg" />
        <param name="href" value="http://hostname/mobile/videos/green.mp4" />
        <param name="target" value="myself" />
        <param name="controller" value="false" />
        <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
        <param name="scale" value="aspect" />
        <embed type="video/quicktime" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" src="http://hostname/mobile/videos/green.jpg" href="http://hostname/mobile/videos/green.mp4" target="myself" controller="false" autoplay="false" scale="aspect" />
    </object>
</noscript>
```

Comment: This is wrong in every way. Android uses completely different XML. Look at the documentation for the MediaPlayer class.

Comment: but some says to use <video...> do you have anything to say?

Comment: There is no <video> that I am aware of. Android and iOS are extremely different, and unless you are using something like the Unity engine, you are not going to be able to use the same code for both. Please look at my answer below.

Comment: @Amplify: I think he's trying to do a web app, not a local app. Regardless, I don't believe Android (or iOS, for that matter) support the WebM format yet.

Comment: @kcoppock you're right, I see that now. The question was tricky to understand!

Answer (score 2):

Check the following link, there seem to be some workarounds, but WebM video is definitely not supported as of yet:

[HTML5 <video> element on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android/3205501#3205501)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try hinting the mp4 video (moving the 'moov' atom at the beginning) with MP4Box or qt-faststart? Android can not play mp4 video progressively if the 'moov' atom is not at the beginning..

Comment: i dont know much about but what i am trying to do is to play the video on both andriod/iphone through html5 as others have stated that i have to use <video> tag in order to do that...

Comment: @Abu Hamzah - Nop, not all mp4/ogv video will play in Android/Iphone in <video> tag. If the 'moov' atom of the mp4 video is not at the beginning it will not play the video. So you may need to use the mp4box (http://www.videohelp.com/tools/mp4box ) or qt-faststart from ffmpeg (http://www.ffmpeg.org ) to move the moov atom at the beginning.

Comment: i am bit confused here, so you saying that i should onvert the video mp4 to ? what format?,  `move the moov atom` i am not sure i understand what do you mean by that. thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Abu Hamzah - Not actually convert, just move the meta info to the beginning.. Here ( http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/11/12/how-to-make-mp4-progressive-with-qt-faststart/ ) are some info regarding this..Hope this will help.

Comment: @Hasan, can you show me a sample code, since i havent worked on this so i have no idea from where to start. - thanks.

Comment: @Abu Hamzah - Have a look at here ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android ).

Comment: i did try the example, before posting this question and it did not work on my android phone any clue?

Answer (score 0):

This is not at all how things are done in Android. For starters take a look at the MediaPlayer class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Also, take the time to look around the rest of the website. It is full of resources for learning how to get started with Android.

Comment: what about iphone, do i have to have a separate page for playing video on iphone?

Answer (score 0):

Your code fragment appear to be an HTML code. But iphone/android application is not an HTML code/pages! I think you should be more specific about what are you trying to do.

For android, application usually consist of JAVA code and UI declared in XML according to android schema (again, not HTML!). In this case, if you need to play video, you should use android API class android.media.MediaPlayer as Amplify91 said before (and this is nothing to do with HTML or XML). If you interested in developing application for android you should go to [official android site for developers](http://developer.android.com).

For iPhone, situation is similar, but instead of java you should develop application using object-C language and API for iPhone/iOS (different to Android API). I think there should be something similar to android's MediaPlayer (but i am not iPhone specialist).

But if your question not about apps, but about web page, that just should be opened in browser from iOS or android device, and about html, then answer is - you should use an HTML5 tag (default browsers from both devices supports HTML5). You can read more about this tag [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_video.asp)

Comment: i am just looking a way to embed videos that can play on andriod and iphone using html5 tag....and i try the sample shows on the link but it does not work, i will post the code in my above updated question. thanks.