# Android - Play Video does not work

Tags: android, video

I'm a newbie on android java programming with Eclipse (I have a .NET background) and fail to get a video played in an emulator (nor on an android htc desire)

My setup:

- Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Version: Helios Service Release 2
- Android SDK and ADT Plugin for Eclipse

The video I'm using is a 3gp video I recorded with my htc desire.

I have tried the 2 approaches with

1. VideoView
2. SurfaceView with a MediaPlayer
   which I took out of the book from Reto Meier "Professional Android 2 Application Development".

I'm targetting Android 2.2 (both in the emulator, as well on my htc desire)

Details

**1. VideoView approach**

getDuration always returns -1 and even after calling videoView.start() isPlaying is false.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity 
{
    private static final String FileName = "VIDEO0015.3gp";
    private static final String MyTag = "MyActivity";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {               
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        videoView.setKeepScreenOn(true);

        File clip=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), FileName);
        if (clip.exists())
        {
            videoView.setVideoPath(clip.getAbsolutePath());
            int duration = videoView.getDuration();

            if (videoView.canSeekForward())
            {
                videoView.seekTo(duration/2);
            }

            videoView.start();
        }
   }
}
```

The main.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<VideoView android:id="@+id/videoView1" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</VideoView>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

**2. SurfaceView with MediaPlayer**
With this approach, I get the correct duration (about 15 sec) and isPlaying is true.
Both nothing is to be seen and also video playing never is completed.

I will add the code if somebody wants to check it.

---

Thanks for any help, I'm getting desperate.

Frank

Comment: Seems odd, could you post your main.xml (don't forget to format it as code - just mark it and press ctrl+k), and have you tried playing another video (not recorded on the phone)?

Comment: @MByD: Thanks for your help. I have added the contents of the main.xml file. I have played around a bit with the layout settings, but no change. I'm really a newbie, so maybe Im doing something fundamentally wrong. About other videos, I tried one other, which failed with a different error. Because the second attempt (with the surfaceView and mediaPlayer) returns the correct duration and says isPlaying = true I assumed that the video is ok. I will check another video. Is there any video that is guaranteed to work?

Comment: I tried your code and got the same result (with valid video), I don't know why, maybe I'll have time to check it later.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem before. Did you try 'hinting' the 3gp video? You can have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794794/how-can-i-make-it-play-video-on-andriod-iphone/5800781#5800781). Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have write some testing video view program before.
And I think maybe is your video file path wrong?
Here is my testing code,

```
public class VideoActivity  extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_view_layout);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

        Uri video = Uri.parse("/sdcard/test_video.mp4");
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();
        }
}
```

And the XML is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VideoView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/VideoView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
</VideoView>
```

AndroidManifest.xml,

```
        <activity android:name=".VideoActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                  android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Hope can help you.

Comment: In this case, the video file is put into the /sdcard root level.

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried your code, but I get _No Launcher activity found! The launch will only sync the application package on the device!_ I'm a newbie so I do not know the cause of the problem.       I think that the path to my video file is OK, because I check it in the code with  `File clip=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), FileName);
        if (clip.exists())`

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't found a solution, `VideoView.getDuration()` will return -1 if the video is not in playback state. The video is not in playback state until it has been prepared. So calling `VideoView.getDuration()` directly after setting the URI does not guarantee that the video has been prepared.

I found this by looking at the source of VideoView:

```
@Override
public int getDuration() {
    if (isInPlaybackState()) {
        return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }

    return -1;
}
```

The solution is to set an OnPreparedListener to your VideoView, and obtain/use the duration once the video is prepared. You can then use `VideoView.getDuration()` or `MediaPlayer.getDuration()`, which are nearly identical.

Solution:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private static final String FileName = "VIDEO0015.3gp";
private static final String MyTag = "MyActivity";

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    videoView.setKeepScreenOn(true);

    File clip = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), FileName);
    if (clip.exists()) {
        videoView.setVideoPath(clip.getAbsolutePath());
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                int duration = videoView.getDuration();
                if (videoView.canSeekForward()) {
                    videoView.seekTo(duration / 2);
                    videoView.start();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}