# How to play inline html5 video in Android Browser

Tags: android, html, video, browser

I'm doing mobile web app, in that i use html5 to play videos, it works fine
But In Android native browser if i click on the video it transfer to native media player. but i want to play it inline
How to do this? thanks

Comment: It was already responded [HERE][1], next time please look in search text box


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piperoman wrote his answer in comments, so I figured I would put the link into an answer for convenience:

[HTML5 <video> element on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android)

Comment: Couldn't find answer. Can u kindly point towards it again if you don't mind?

Comment: the link is to stackoverflow.  should still work.