# Autolay video for WebRTC application on iPhone

Tags: webrtc, html5-video, tokbox

I'm working on a Webrtc application, and with the iOS mobile browser's limitation, I can't autoplay video with audio without user interaction. When a user clicks "Joins the session" I can run video.play() for existing streams. However, it requires a new user interaction to unmute every new stream. Any suggestion on how to autoplay not muted videos without a user clicking a play button?

Comment: are you using the OpenTok JS SDK?

Comment: @abdulajet yes, I'm using OpenTok JS SDK?

Comment: I think you need to set `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` to true. check out this project that uses OpenTok on iOS https://github.com/Vonage-Community/sample-video_express-swift_kotlin-video_express_native/blob/a872e358a0b3e8977b855d5cdc2fc1928eb028b8/VideoExpressiOS/VideoExpressiOS/VideoExpressViewController.swift#L21

Comment: @abdulajet, thanks for your answer, but I have a web application, not iOS.

Comment: similar process for web https://stackoverflow.com/a/39149267/9824067