# Html5 Video Tag on Android Phone using Phone gap

Tags: android, html, cordova

I want to play an video on android using Phone Gap, Html5 and Jquery-mobile.

But i am not able to get the video and got the below error

> 03-16 16:13:58.057: E/libEGL(551): call to OpenGL ES API with no
>   current context (logged once per thread) 03-16 16:13:58.126:
>   E/libEGL(551): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged
>   once per thread) 03-16 16:13:58.137: E/libEGL(551): call to OpenGL ES
>   API with no current context (logged once per thread) 03-16
>   16:13:58.137: E/libEGL(551): call to OpenGL ES API with no current
>   context (logged once per thread) 03-16 16:13:58.137: E/libEGL(551):
>   call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
>   03-16 16:13:58.137: E/libEGL(551): call to OpenGL ES API with no
>   current context (logged once per thread) 03-16 16:17:08.816:
>   E/MediaPlayer(551): error (1, -1004) 03-16 16:17:08.816:
>   E/MediaPlayer(551): Error (1,-1004)

**
  Html Code:
**

```
<body>     
<section>
<div>
<video id="video" height="240" width="360" autoplay autobuffer controls >
<source src="http://css.flepstudio.org/demo/video_player/assets/videos/21_Jump_Street.mp4">
<source src="http://css.flepstudio.org/demo/video_player/assets/videos/21_Jump_Street.ogv" type="video/ogg">    Video is not present
</video>
</div>           
</section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Plugin:

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.in/2011/11/video-player-plugin-for-phonegap.html

Also look at whitelist for android.
Look at a  file in /res/xml in your project filename: PhoneGap.xml

~K

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't need neither `jquery` nor `PhoneGap`. PLease take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android/8952025#8952025) very popular thread. `<video>` tag is part of HTML 5, however there are definitely issues of getting it work on all phones. I have shared in the same thread [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8952025/1108032), that seem to work for all kinds of phones. Hopefully you will find it helpful.