# htmls audio and video not working in android

Tags: android, html

I have an inline audio file to be played in android using html5. I understand that android does not support the `<audio>` tag. I also tried using the `<video>` tag. But it is still not working. I also want it to autoplay. Currently the controls are being displayed but the audio is not playing. If anyone can please help me? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This have been always an issue with the android support of HTML 5 tags: they perform rather differently on different devices. I can point you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android) huge, yet useful, thread of the video tag. I still recommend [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8952025/1108032) there, as it seems to be a good general approach if it works for you - have the html code invoke native intents.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I had developed a webview for displaying the html5 content it was working perfectly fine uptil some time before but now it is showing "unfortunately activity has stopped"