# Stream from single MP4 file direct link in exoplayer or any other player for android

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer

Straight to the point,
I have direct link to MP4 file and
I'm using exoplayer for streaming videos from a firebase database where url is stored. Suppose the mp4 url is of file location in firebase storage or common direct link. How can I stream the MP4 with different qualities option in exoplayer without creating separate MP4 files for different qualities in the storage. Or if any suggestions for other player for android **(except YouTube, but similar)**

Comment: Does your MP4 file actually have multiple bitrates of the streams inside it?  If not, how do you expect to do this without transcoding?

Comment: Ok thanks, now do I have to convert MP4 in some format and then link it, might be m3u8, or MP4 only with mp4box (saw here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35239044/mpeg-dash-video-stream-with-just-single-mp4-file) will file work with exoplayer?