# How should I make my mobile website support video playing in iphone, android?

Tags: android, asp.net, ios, mobile, web

I want to develop a mobile version of my website, in which I need to embed youtube video/ upload my own flv file and play it in my website, How should I implement this? Should I develop an Flash player by myself? How can I make iPhone play my flv files/Youtube ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some answers here might help and the first answer claims it works in iphone as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your videos on youtube and add them to your website using `iframe`:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID"
   width="yourwidth" height="yourheight"></iframe>
```

It will automatically switch to the HTML5 player if the device doesn't support flash.

Comment: Is it possible for me to play it directly in my website with flash/html5?

Comment: Yes, if you access your website from a device which doesn't support flash, it will show HTML5 player.

Comment: If I don't want to use youtube, then is there any other solutions?

Comment: Well, if you really want to support FLV video playback on non-flash devices, YouTube is the only option I can see.