# android video html 5 not working

Tags: android, html, video, html5-video

I am trying to play my webm video on my android.

my code is:

```
<video width="290" height="517" autoplay loop>
    <source src="/assets/videos/livematch.mp4" type="video/mp4;">
    <source src="/assets/videos/livematch.webm" type="video/webm;">
</video>
```

I tried without semicolons as well `...type="video/mp4"...`
When I open the page the placeholder of the video is black.
When I am trying to download the clip (press and hold on it) it actually saves the mp4.
How should i write the code so it will automatically recognise the device?

Answer (score -1):

Hey I would try to remove the type attribute like showed in the first link I provided. Otherwise you can try to manually call video.play() like showed in the second link.

[Playing HTML5 Videos in Browser -- What Works for Most Android Devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804830/playing-html5-videos-in-browser-what-works-for-most-android-devices)

[HTML5 <video> element on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android)

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work either...
when i press to download (only as a debug method, to see what was recognised by the android mobile browser) is still downloading mp4 and doesnt play it in the site.