# Video and audio formats for HTML5 app in Android

Tags: android, html5-video, html5-audio

First, I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android), but it's a few years old and support for these things might have changed.

I'm developing an HTML5 app for Android using an IDE (HTML5 Builder) that allows to export the HTML5 app to an Android APK. I'm doing that and everything works fine except the video and audio files.

In that app I have one video in mp4 format, and a few audios in mp3 format. When I run that app as a web-app in the internet browser of a desktop and in an Android device the video and the audios work perfectly. However, when I export that app as an APK and install it in an Android device, everything works fine (navigation, css, images, etc) except the video and the audios.

Is it a problem of the format? I've been doing some research and it seems that mp4 and mp3 should be accepted... Besides, I've followed [this method](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/30/encoding-video-for-android/) to encode the video as explained in [this article](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/) (which is the same method explained in the question I mention above) but still the video doesn't work.

Any help with this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First I will state that with me I've experienced a hit or miss with mobile devices. Some mobile devices will work fine with my code other times they wont work at all when using audio or video. I know the following works with iPhone, and supports my primary android device but not all android devices.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

I recomend making the same video files for all 3 formats, this way if a device doesn't support one format but supports another you'll be in luck. The same is for audio but you use the audio tags.

I would recomend installing the following Android Apps on your device to see if your device supports all of the HTML5 features. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mds.phonegapapijqm and https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phonegap.phonegapdeveloper

I know you said you weren't using phonegap but still those apps are very handy for testing HTML apps for android in general.