# Playing a video in Android Application using HTML5 Video tag

Tags: android, html, iframe, cordova, html5-video

I am developing an Android App. I want to play video using HTML5 `<video>` tag. The tag works fine on browsers but the video doesn't play on emulator. Here is my code:

```
<video id="player" type="text/html" width="350" height="350">
  <source src="media/v2.mp4"></source>                      
</video>
```

I also tried using `<iframe>` as follows

```
<iframe src="media/v2.mp4" width="400px" height="400px"></iframe>
```

But both do not work. Please help me fix this. I am using Cordova 2.6.0.

Comment: Why you are more specifici with <video> when there are easy plugins

Comment: @Purus Suggest me few. I am new to using plugins for the same.

Comment: Maybe this post would be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android

Comment: @jakewp11 I have the post that you mentioned and others on stackoverflow. But none of them helped!