# embedding video on html page in android web app

Tags: android, html

```
<script>
function addvideo() {
   var Searchtxt = document.getElementById('eventVideo').value;
   //  alert(Searchtxt);
   //  document.getElementById("video").innerHTML+="<video src="+Searchtxt+" style='width:85px;height:85px'/>&nbsp;";
   document.getElementById("video").innerHTML="<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAWtBlRW6hM" width="320" height="190" frameborder="2"></iframe>";
}
</script>
```

my body code in same page :

```
<input type="text" name="eventVideo" id="eventVideo"  placeholder="Video Links" value="" data-theme="b"  />
```

I want to embedd thumbnail videos on my page when user paste the link in textbox.

Comment: Check this link

[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android )

Comment: thnkss but what i want is to add the video thumbnails on paste of its link in textbox