# HTML5 video has sound but no video. Unsolved for a month now

Tags: android, cordova

Created an app using phonegap on Android.

Everything works great except videos will not play in any shape or form. There is only the audio.

Error:

E/libEGL(1441): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)

Tried using non-embedded videos, different formats, different embeds, changing config.xml settings, basically about 30-40 different solutions. And have been working on this for over 40+ hours now.

I read the long thread about this error on the PhoneGap support forum from about 11 months ago where it was a bug that was going to be fixed. But so far nobody has introduced any idea that resolves this issue.

Has anyone ever overcome this?

PhoneGap ver. (Cordova 2.7)
Android SDK 4.112

Comment: could you provide more information like the mobile version you are working on? can other browsers play the video? If browsers(webview) can play the video then so can phonegap. Also have you tried it in different mobiles?

Comment: This is what I found about this ages ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android

Answer (score 0):

After several weeks we finally solved this problem by using Adobe Build.