# How do I make the html5 video tag to work on Android 4.x

Tags: javascript, android, html, video, web-applications

I have a web app (HTML5 + js + mp4 animations) That I want to encapsulate within a Android webview. Problem is that the mp4 animations (simple html5 video tag with local mp4 files) are not running on android 4.x devices. What are my alternatives? Animated gifs? Flash animations?

The code is very straight forward:

Html:

```
<video id="myvid"></video>
```

JS:

```
var video = window.gedElementById('myvid');
video.src = "../movies/myvid.mp4";
video.play(); // Doesn't work on Andoroid 4.x
```

I have worked on this problem for many weeks now and I have given up. So I'm looking for alternatives. Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe this is helpful for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android

Comment: I'll have a go on it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you convert it to a file type which is playable? Or you could host it online and pull it in from the server.

Comment: Online would actually do the trick. But the requirements is media offline. We finally decided to skip Android 4.x for this and go for the future with Android 5 versions and onwards. After two weeks of working with this. I cannot say I would recommend to use web technologies for video/audio animations for Android versions 4 and below. It's a real mess.