# HTML5 video element not working on Android and iPhone

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have used 5 video in htmt5 `video` element as a slider. It is not working on Android and iPhone device. Just only show a single image. This is my site http://devpgc.buysidedesign.com/

I have used following code

```
   <video id="video" autoplay loop muted>
          <source src="http://devpgc.buysidedesign.com/images/video/InvestorAligned_1.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
           <source src="http://devpgc.buysidedesign.com/images/video/InvestorAligned_1.webm" type="video/webm"/>
            <source src="http://devpgc.buysidedesign.com/images/video/InvestorAligned_1.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>
      </video>
```

I have also try to follow this link [HTML5 <video> element on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android) but no luck. Please tell me the solution.

Comment: Do you mean in Chrome Mobile and Safari Mobile? i think they are not totally supported compared to desktop

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.addEventListener('click',function(){
  video.play();
},false);
```

[Source](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/)

Comment: you put it between '<script type="text/javascript"></script>' after the body tag?