# html5 video not playing in android

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had developed a mobile page to play mp4 video.
I had put trigger,but it doesn't work in android.
The following is my code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#button1").click(function() {

          $('#video1').get(0).play();

        });

        $("#button1").trigger("click");

    });
</script>
```

```
<input type='button' value='Button 1' id='button1'>
<video id="video1" src="v1.mp4" />
```

how to make this code work with android.

Comment: Can you play the video at all? I mean without the button? If you add some alert after calling `play()`, does it show?

Comment: yes it work when i add alert.jquery text append also working inside button click.

Comment: try dis link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android