# HTML5 audio and video do not work on android 4.4.2

Tags: android, html, audio, video, single-page-application

I am develop SPA application. In application i use

```
 <pre>
        <video id="video-container" width="720" height="480" data-bind="event : { ended: $root.closeVid }" controls preload="auto">       
            <source src="assets/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="assets/video/video.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
            <source src="assets/video/video.ogv" type="video/ogg" />      
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</pre>
```

and audio

```
<pre>      

     var audio = new Audio(dataModel.content.guidance.voiceover);
       audio.play();

</pre>
```

Video and audio do not want to work on android 4.4.2. But works good on 5.1 ad 4.2.x.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you using the default android browser?

Comment: Are you using the same chrome version on both the devices?

Comment: Different one. On android 4.4 i have Chrome 40.0.2214.109, on 5.1 i have Chrome 44.0.2403.133

Comment: Try using the same version(latest).Audio and Video is new in HTML.Some older browsers(versions) may not support it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android
This has the answer to your question.

Comment: There are certain rules for HTML multimedia to work on android.Visit the above link.You will find the most appropriate solution.